# Calling extension method (e.g. "Union") on generic-typed parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

We are trying to construct a library routine that takes a generic type parameter. We have run into an issue where the extension method "Union" is not recognized as valid for the generically typed parameter no matter how we constrain the type.

Here is a trivial, greatly simplified example to illustrate the problem:

```
private IQueryable<int> Test(IQueryable<int> temp1, IQueryable<int> temp2)
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2); // compiles fine
}

private T Test<T>(T temp1, T temp2) where T : IQueryable
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2); // Error 15  'T' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and no extension method 'Union' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found
}
```

The problem seems to be that Union is implemented as an extension method of IQueryable, rather than as part of the IQueryable interface itself. It seems like there must be a fairly simple way to make this work, but I have been looking all through StackOverflow and on Google, without any luck. Any help much appreciated.

=================================

Edit:

It is true that this will compile:

```
private IQueryable<T> Test<T>(IQueryable<T> temp1, IQueryable<T> temp2)
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2); // compiles fine
}
```

However, this doesn't get at my real question, which is why the extension methods were not recognized on the generic-typed parameter. This solution simply does away with the "generic-ism" in the critical spot of the (as noted, greatly simplified) example. I think, as one answer notes, it is true that the distinction between `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<>` is important.

For the record, I also tried:

```
private C<T> Test<C, T>(C<T> temp1, C<T> temp2) // The type parameter 'C' cannot be used with type arguments
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2);
}
```

This gives the compiler error noted.

Comment: Why are you ensuring `T` implements `IQueryable` and not `IQueryable<T>`?

Answer (score 4):

The code does not compile because this does not compile either:

```
IQueryable a, b;
a.Union(b);
```

Because `Union` works on an `IQueryable<T>`, not an `IQueryable`.

```
IQueryable<TItem> Test<T, TItem>(T temp1, T temp2) where T : IQueryable<TItem>
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2);
}
```

You need to make it the generic version of the interface and specify the item type. The return type can't be `T` because `Union` does not return `T`, it returns `IQueryable<TItem>`.

In fact, I think you meant:

```
IQueryable<TItem> Test<TItem>(IQueryable<TItem> temp1, IQueryable<TItem> temp2)
{
    return temp1.Union(temp2);
}
```

Which is simpler.

Comment: Thanks, usr; I was not thinking about the difference between `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

there is difference between inheriting from  something and implement something the issue is more like [composition  over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)  you should implement

```
 IQueryable<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue I was wondering about here was why the extension methods were not recognized. Thanks to the answer from "usr" for pointing the way. I was not thinking about the distinction between `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>`. Once I got to poking around with that, I was able to hit upon the real answer that I wanted, which seems to be as follows (again, this is a trivial implementation, but it implements the principle I was after):

```
    private C Test<C, T>(C temp1, C temp2) where C : IQueryable<T>
    {
        return (C)temp1.Union(temp2); // compiles fine
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!